# How do I set cookie to be secure .NET Core?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I've run into problems using Identity Server 4. It's the common problem that requires SameSite=None and secure cookies. While I managed to set SameSite to None, I didn't set cookies to be secure.

I tried searching online but couldn't find any complete solution. I will need information where to use that part of code too, since I'm not experienced.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie settings like this

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
    .AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = ...;
    });
```

for more information read [Cookie authentication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html).